# Do the androids need to kill their owners in Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?

Tags: quotes, do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep

I'm writing my BA thesis on Philip K. Dick's *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?*. In the Polish translation of the book, there is an indication that an android needs to kill its owner to get from Mars to Earth.  Referencing this assertion would improve my thesis greatly, but I cannot find the corresponding statement in the English version of the book.

**Can someone please give me some indication on where in the text it can be found, or some other information regarding this assertion?**

Answer (score 5):

These are the closest I can find to what you're looking for. They're from chapter 11:

> “He doesn’t know; he doesn’t suspect; he doesn’t have the slightest
>   idea. Otherwise he couldn’t live out a life as a bounty hunter, a
>   human occupation—hardly an android occupation.” Garland gestured
>   toward Rick’s briefcase. “Those other carbons, the other suspects
>   you’re supposed to test and retire. I know them all.” He paused, then
>   said, “We all came here together on the same ship from Mars. Not
>   Resch; he stayed behind another week, receiving the synthetic memory
>   system.” He was silent then.

and:

> “Then at one time an authentic Garland existed,” Phil Resch said. “And
>   somewhere along the way got replaced.” His sharklike lean face twisted
>   and he struggled to understand. “Or—I’ve been impregnated with a false
>   memory system. Maybe I only remember Garland over the whole time.
>   But—” His face, suffused now with growing torment, continued to twist
>   and work spasmodically. “Only androids show up with false memory
>   systems; it’s been found ineffective in humans.”

Comment: so there is no simple and straight to the point sentence in the book, that tells the reader, that the  androids, when they want to escape the mars, need to kill their owners?
@edit - I'm asking, because it is possible, that it was the mistake of the translator.

Comment: @Wielki Przedwieczny: I wasn't able to find one. Of course, I was only doing text searches for key words like "kill", "owner", "master", "mars", "escape", etc.

Comment: already found it ;) answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Got it!

Chapter 3, page 27 (in my edition):

> Humanoid robot, which had killed its master, which had been equipped with an intelligence greater that that of many human beings, which had no regard for animals, which possessed no ability to feel empathic joy for another life form's success or grief as its defeat - that, for him, epitomized The Killers

This is the quote about Mercerism, killing, and retiring androids, i.e. "The Killers".

Comment: I saw that one, but I didn't include it because I thought your original question was specific to the Nexus-6s that had escaped from mars.

Comment: That quote is really about specific androids that had killed ("which had") and begins "For Dekard *an escaped humanoid robot, which had [...]". I don't think this answers your question about some general compulsion or requirement (a need).